# jQuery - Expand div and make no other one move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some divs and have some effects on it thorugh jQuery. When I hover over a div it expands. But then the divs beside and beneath it move along with it. I want the same effect like the expandable user card given on stackoverflow after 1k repuration.

[This](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mareebsiddiqui/MvzFC/show/) is what I have done.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var delay = 1000;
    $(".user").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#eee");
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({
            width: '350px',
            height: '200px'
        });
        $(this).find("img").delay(delay).animate({
            marginTop: '+=5px',
            marginLeft: '+=5px'
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#fff");
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({
            width: '300px',
            height: '50px'
        });
        $(this).find("img").delay(delay).animate({
            marginTop: '-=5px',
            marginLeft: '-=5px'
        });
    });
});
```

So in a nutshell:

1. I want the divs to remain on place when a div gets expanded
2. I want that if the mouse remains 0.5 seconds on the div `.user` then the div should be expanded else nothing should happen.

Comment: The divs are gonna move when you are changing the widths

Comment: If you really want them to not "appear" to move, then you'll need to place each "user" in a parent container with the exact size you want while collapsed `width: 300px;`. Then, instead of making parent wider on hover, make child `div.class=user` expand in width and make it's `positioin: absolute`. Dont forget to set parent to `position: relative`

Comment: @SpYk3HH The best analogy to describe your idea is a "tool tip", you click or mouse-over an element that causes an overlay to appear with new content.  Using absolutely positioned elements will work nicely.

Comment: @SpYk3HH can you provide an answer? I can't figure it out myself! :/

Comment: something like: http://fiddle.jshell.net/3skQN/1/show/

Comment: But they are coming below each other :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done purely in CSS3, and here's what you're looking for: Wrap each `<div class="user">` in a `<div class="userWrap">`. Then, use the following CSS:

```css
.userWrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}
.userWrap:hover {
    z-index: 2;
}
.user {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s;
}
.user:hover {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    transition: width 0.3s ease 0.5s, height 0.3s ease 0.5s;
}
```

To achieve the desired effect.

[**See a demo here.**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MvzFC/24/)

Comment: why doesn't this work with "overflow: hidden" on the wrapper? to only reveal the contents when you hover?